# Seleccionar Fecha más reciente SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla `Clientes` como la siguiente:

| Nombre | Apellido1 | Apellido2 | Cantidad | Departamento | Fecha |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Juan | Lopez | Garcia | 50 | A | 2010-04-26 |
| Juan | Lopez | Garcia | 60 | B | 2010-05-26 |
| Javier | Rodrigo | Fuente | 70 | C | 2011-06-26 |
| Laura | Pasa | Gonzales | 80 | D | 2011-06-26 |

Quiero recuperar con la clave Nombre, Apellido1 y Apellido2 el campo `Cantidad`. Sin embargo, si existe más de una fila por cliente quiero la más reciente. Por ejemplo, vemos en la tabla anterior que el cliente Juan Lopez Garcia está dos veces pero solo queremos seleccionar 2010-05-26 ya que es el más reciente. Además Solo evaluaremos las filas que tengan por campo el `Departamento` A, B o C.

Para sacar los clientes que tengan una fecha más reciente hago lo siguiente:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Nombre, Apellido1, Apellido2, Cantidad 
FROM Clientes
WHERE FECHA = (SELECT MAX(FECHA) FROM Clientes)
```

Con esto, me falta añadir la condición del Departamento:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Nombre, Apellido1, Apellido2, Cantidad 
FROM Clientes
WHERE FECHA = (SELECT MAX(FECHA) FROM Clientes)
AND Departamento = 'A' OR Departamento = 'B' OR Departamento = 'C';
```

Sin embargo, no funciona. La salida esperada debería ser:

```
Juan, Lopez, Garcia, 60, B, 2010-05-26
Javier, Rodrigo, Fuente, 70, C, 2011-06-26
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que podríamos obtener ese dato sustituyendo el `where` de fecha por un `order by`, para ordenar el cómo te van a mostrar los resultados. quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Nombre, Apellido1, Apellido2, Cantidad 
FROM Clientes
WHERE Departamento = 'A' OR Departamento = 'B' OR Departamento = 'C'
order by FECHA DESC);
```